# WPF vs XNA vs Surface for gesture based interface

Tags: wpf, xna, pixelsense

I wonder which of these 3 frameworks / combination of them is most suitable for gesture-based interface (based on touch or motion recognition)?

I see online some directions, of using WPF and Surface, but nothing concrete.

I will appreciate if someone who already worked on this can suggest an approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about targetting Windows 7, WPF 4 + the "Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch" are the most efficient way to go.  WPF 4 has built in low level APIs for touch and the Surface Toolkit extends that with a suite of controls that are optimized for touch and gestures.  See my presentation on this topic from PDC '09:  http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/CL27

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Adrman deleted his post, but I'm going to re-post his link to Shawn Hargreave's post about the touch API on windows:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/09/09/touch-input-on-windows-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

If you're interested in still using XNA for your project, there are definitely still options as Shawn "touches" upon in the end of his post. For example, here is an article on the XNA UK UG site that shows how to implement touch on windows:
http://xna-uk.net/blogs/randomchaos/archive/2010/02/10/xna-and-windows-7-multi-touch.aspx

Now, that pretty much ties you to the API, but it stands to reason that you could refactor this so that it was more generic, and then eventually just use the built-in touch API (assuming they implement touch on windows, which I believe they will).